# Which port to use for Network discovery application

Tags: sockets, udp, port, winsock

I have been given the task of creating a network discovery application which broadcasts its existence to other applications and listens for other applications broadcasting on the same network.

I'm tackling this problem by using UDP sockets. But the problem I have is when creating the sockaddr_in data structure for the server, I don't know what port number to use, i.e. I don't know which port number is the most appropriate to set to the variable sin_port.

Any help with my issue is greatly appreciated and if my question is not clear enough then please say so in the comments so I can make it clearer

Comment: Any port you like, as long as it isn't already reserved by IANA. If there already was an appropriate port it would already be reserved, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it be only as a source of inspiration, you may want to have a look at the SSDP (Simple Service Discovery Protocol) - it's UDP based, port 1900, broadcast + unicast, and is precisely intended to address your problem:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Service_Discovery_Protocol

http://upnp.org/sdcps-and-certification/standards/device-architecture-documents/

(section 1, "discovery", is 20 pages long and covers SSDP)